# How do I get my list to read certain values?

Tags: python, list, function, split, python-3.5

I am a beginner at python. I have a code that reads a text file from my computer and converts all the text to int. I am struggling with the last few lines in the analyze golf scores function.

I need to tell the code that for a score under 280 to take these values and get the amount, which I know to use Len(score) for but I am going wrong with getting the values in the first place. It should print the number of scores below 180, but I keep getting errors and I am so lost! Any help is appreciated at all! Thank you so much!!!

My error is in the last six lines of code! I don't know how to get it to read the values under 280 in the list :(

The error is:

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'##
```

on the line:

```
    if score < 280:
```

```
def open_and_read_golf_scores():
    raw_scores = open("golfscores.txt", "r")
    scores = []

    for current_line in raw_scores:
        values = current_line.split(",")
        scores.append(values[2])

    raw_scores.close()

    return scores

def analyze_golf_scores():

    scores = open_and_read_golf_scores()
    total = 0
    for score in scores:
        score = score[0:3]
        total = total +int(score)

    ave = total/len(score)

print("Average score =", ave)

for score in scores:
    if score < 280:
        scores.append(values)
        below_par = total + len(score)
print("The number of scores below par is ", below_par)
```

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mre]

Comment: Your indentation looks wrong -- it's not clear if there's a copy+paste error or if that's the source of the problems you're hitting.  Please review that and edit your question to include the exact code you're running *and* the exact errors you're receiving.

Comment: I have edited the code x

Comment: Now there's not enough code to run -- it's not clear what `scores` or `values` are.  And you still haven't included your error.  :(

Comment: hold on, ill fix it my bad

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239738/discussion-between-amanda-and-samwise).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code looks problematic:

```
    for score in scores:
        score = score[0:3]
        total = total +int(score)

        ave = total/len(score)

    print("Average score =", ave)

    for score in scores:
        if score < 280:
            scores.append(values)
            below_par = total + len(score)
    print("The number of scores below par is ", below_par)
```

- The thing you're computing as `ave` is not the numeric average of the scores, it's the total divided by the number of digits in each score (which is 3).  Is that what you meant to compute?  Did you mean to divide by `len(scores)` instead?
- Your `scores` are strings, and you're trying to compare them to the number `280`, which is why you're getting that `TypeError`.  You should convert them to `int` as you did above, or better yet, have `open_and_read_golf_scores` return them as `ints` in the first place.
- Right after where you hit that error, you try to do something with `values`, which is unbound in this scope.  Maybe you meant to use `score`?

A lot of problems will probably go away if your `open_and_read_golf_scores` function just returns the scores as ints:

```
from typing import List

def open_and_read_golf_scores() -> List[int]:
    with open("golfscores.txt", "r") as raw_scores:
        return [
            int(current_line.split(",")[2][:3]) 
            for current_line in raw_scores
        ]
```

*Note: I kept the logic of slicing each `score` to its first three characters, but I have no idea why that's necessary because I can't see the contents of the file -- it feels like it might actually lead to a bug.  Is every score really exactly three digits, with appropriate zero-padding?  Is there some extra stuff after the score?  What is that stuff?  Could there be an safer way to get rid of it than making the assumption that the number is always 3 digits long?*

Now your `analyze_golf_scores` function can be much simpler, because you can do basic mathematical operations on `scores` without having to convert each item in a loop:

```
from statistics import mean


def analyze_golf_scores() -> None:
    scores = open_and_read_golf_scores()
    ave = mean(scores)
    below_par = sum(score < 280 for score in scores)

    print(f"Average score = {ave}")
    print(f"The number of scores below par is {below_par}")
```